# Distance between zeros of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuous-homomorphisms

Dears,

Let $f(x):=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}^{k}$, for each $x\in[a,b]$, where $a_{i}$ are real numbers (not nulls) and $b_{i}>0$. Assume that $f$ has, at least, two ceros in $[a,b]$. Then, I want to estimate the minimal distance between two consecutive zeros of $f$.

Somebody know some result (paper, book, ...) related with this question? Or, How do you think can be processed this issue?

Thank for your time.

Comment: There is no $x$ in your def of $f(x)$. please clarify via an [edit].

Comment: Also, you seem to have indexed $a_i$ and $b_i$ which are independent of your summation index.

Comment: Sorry, you are right: $f(x):=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}^{x}$, i.e. $f(x)$ is a exponential polynomial.